# AdMob ad don't show(unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

When I am using unity, the console shows Dummy LoadAD, Dummy Show, etc.
But when I test it on my phone it does show any AD.
I set these two functions on two-button. bannerAD button does not show bannerAD. videoAD button will close my app

### There's my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class admanageger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text adstatus;
    BannerView bannerView;
    RewardedAd rewardedAd;
    string appID = "ca-app-pub-#####~#####";
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Awake()
    {

    }
    void Start()
    {
         MobileAds.Initialize(appID);

    }
    public void showbannerAD()
{
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-####/####";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-###/#####";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
    public void showvideoAD()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-#####/####";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-#####/#####";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif
            this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(adUnitId);

            // Create an empty ad request.
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
         this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);
        this.rewardedAd.Show();

    }
}
```

Am I do something wrong or and setting need about Admob?

Answer (score 0):

AdMob won't show any ads on Unity Editor. You should always test your Ad related stuff by building and testing on your phone.

Comment: Make sure your AdMob account is approved. If you just created the project on AdMob, it may take up to 24h to ads to show.

Comment: my account has register 48 hour , even i use the demo ID of  admob it also can't show the AD