# Admob Unity Test Ads are not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, game-development

I have everything set up correctly for my Unity game ads. When I run the ad, the console shows the ShowAD() message, but no ads are seen. I am using the test ad id and did the sdk and jdk are correctly installed.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63578879/7111561 -> `AdMob won't show any ads on Unity Editor. You should always test your Ad related stuff by building and testing on your phone.` also go through [Common reasons for ads not showing](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

you can not see the ads in the unity editor , you should make an APK file and run it on your device
BTW are you also using test app ID in Assets->Google Mobile Ads-> Setting-> Admob App ID?
in my case this was the problem.